# SQL error Command not ended properly with sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help

```
    select abc_mgr.ldap_test.*
from (select abc_mgr.ldap_test.*
      from abc_mgr.ldap_test
      order by (case STATUS when 'ACTV' then 1 when 'NOTACTIV' then 2 WHEN 'DIS' then 3 else 4 END),
               (case BILL_SYS when 'V' then 1 when 'S' then 2 when 'E' then 3 else 4 END)
    ) abc_mgr.ldap_test
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: table  name is abc_mgr.ldap_test

Comment: Where and how do you run that statement?

Comment: ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER and select the whole query and execute(F9)

Comment: Maybe you have an rogue non-display character.  I just tried:  `With T AS (SELECT 'ACTV' as Status,'V' as BS from dual)
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by (case status when 'ACTV' then 1 when 'NOTACTIV' then 2 WHEN 'DIS' then 3 else 4 END),
               (case BS when 'V' then 1 when 'S' then 2 when 'E' then 3 else 4 END)
    ) t
where rownum = 1;` and it ran fine.

Comment: It's fine as it is, although the brackets around the `case` expressions are redundant. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : Can you check if I using this table name, it is giving error

Comment: @MananKapoor . . . Your table name is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` clause doesn't have parenthesis. Just remove them and you should be OK:

```
select t.*
from   (select   t.*
        from     t
        order by case status when 'ACTV'     then 1 
                             when 'NOTACTIV' then 2
                             when 'DIS'      then 3 
                             else 4 
                 end,
                 case BS when 'V' then 1 
                         when 'S' then 2 
                         when 'E' then 3 
                         else 4 
                end
       ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Alternatively, if you're using Oracle 12c or newer, you could just use the modern `fetch` clause:

```
select   t.* 
from     t
order by case status when 'ACTV'     then 1 
                     when 'NOTACTIV' then 2
                     when 'DIS'      then 3 
                     else 4 
         end,
         case BS when 'V' then 1 
                 when 'S' then 2 
                 when 'E' then 3 
                 else 4 
        end
fetch first row only -- Here!
```